# Socket programming - why do we not convert sin_family to network order?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

Below is an example of a valid socket creation (in C):

```
  // Construct local address structure
  struct sockaddr_in servAddr;                  // Local address
  memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));       // Zero out structure
  servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                // IPv4 address family
  servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // Any incoming interface
  servAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort);          // Local port
```

We need to convert the address and port to network order but not the address family. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sin_family` isn't sent over the network, so there's no need to use network byte order. It's a local flag for your operating system only. It indicates the polymorphic type of the `struct sockaddr *` pointer, because IPv4 isn't the only format. An `AF_UNIX` address doesn't get IP address and port fields, for instance.

Comment: VG. I never understood why this wasn't built into the kernel. The kernel has to deal with the port number as a native `short` for example.